# Non-volatile replacement for INDIRECT function in an online Excel Sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to find an alternative for INDIRECT to reference cell value as a sheet name in a function.

Context:
Let's say I have 20 sheets with different names. I need a function that will allow for dynamic reference of a sheet name, so that I can pull date from cells in selected sheet.

I use a drop down list with the names of the Sheets (A2) and I wanted for my cell (B2) to return value of specific cells in the chosen sheet (let's say I need the value of C3 from one of the sheets in the dropdown list). Since the workbook contains a lot of data, I don't want to rely on INDIRECT to avoid slowing the processing.

I have tried using the INDEX function:

(B2)
='INDEX(A2,1)'!C3

However, for some reason excel thinks I'm trying to access an external workbook by the name "INDEX(A2,1)".

Can anyone please suggest how to make it work without the use of INDIRECT?

Comment: How can we reproduce without proper examples/data/names?

Comment: There really is no way to not use INDIRECT() when the worksheet is the variable.  If it were the column or row then yes INDEX works, but not when it is the worksheet.

Comment: That depends on how he wants to use it. There are openings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ifa8.png